# Controlling timed execution in Spring-based Pojo in Java EE

Tags: java, spring, timer

I'd like to have a Spring-managed bean schedule execution of itself (or some other bean, simple factoring) if certain conditions are met (i.e. checking successul startup etc.)

I'd also like to be able to see and control the timer from within the application, which will be running on a Java EE 5-compliant container.

Not sure how best to do this - I know about the dangers of doing thread management myself in an EE environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a base class that is a wrapper to schedule background tasks (could be e.g. an `Executor` or `TimerTask`) and be parameterized by the timing intervals or even the task to schedule and you could derive more specific classes specialized on certain tasks.

These you would configure/instantiate via Spring configuration and of course your app could modify these via the properties of the classes/beans.

Concerning thread management, I also had concerns regarding threads since JavaEE specs (I believe specifically EJB specs) disallow it but this perhaps depends on the container. For example in Tomcat which of course is **not** a fully EE container, I never had issue with my own threads.
You don't mention which container you are interested in.

Also (friends here can correct if I am wrong) my understanding is that threads are disallowed e.g. in EJB containers etc if you access various resources handled by the container threads.
So if you only want to do some e.g. sanity checks (checking succesful startup) and similar, I don't think that this would be an issue. But this is MHO. I am not sure to be honest